# Rails - Find the user with the most posts over the last week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My Rails app has a user model and a pins model. pins are album reviews that get posted to the site and the pins belong_to the user. I have a stats page on the site that lists interesting stats about the site's content. I'm trying to list a "Reviewer of the week" which will show which user posted the most reviews over the last week. This is the code I put in my page controller:

```
@user_week = User.includes(:pins).where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago.utc).count(:all, :group => 'name', :order => 'count(*) DESC').first
```

I then call it in the view:

```
<%= @user_week[0] %>
```

For some reason this is giving me a user, but not actually the user with the most posts over teh last week. It gives me ["User", 1] and it doesn't change when I post more often. Is my code wrong?

Also, how can I call the user's image from @user_week? It currently returns the name and pin count.

User column names:

```
["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "name", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "slug", "twitter", "lastfm", "status", "admin"]
```

Pin column names:

```
["id", "description", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "image_remote_url", "artist", "album", "date", "rank", "video_html", "video", "rating", "year"]
```

Comment: can you post the columns of both user and pins models?

Comment: @arun15thmay I added them above

Comment: `@user_week = User.joins(:pins).where('pins.created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago.utc).count(:all, :group => 'name', :order => 'count(*) DESC')`  can you try this?

Comment: @arun15thmay That worked! You're the man. Now do you know how I would show the user_week.image in the view. user_week returns an array as of now like ["Tony", 4]

Comment: is it returning array of such arrays or only one such array?

Comment: @arun15thmay I figured out the image issue. (see my answer below) Post your code as an answer for the user_week above and I'll mark it as complete. Thanks again.

Comment: I think there might be problems with your code. If 2 users have the same name, won't it create any problems?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44443/discussion-between-tony-tambe-and-arun15thmay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@users = User.joins(:pins).group('users.id').where('pins.created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago.utc).order('count(pins.id) desc').limit(1).first
```

will return an array of users. then use the following code

```
<%= link_to (image_tag @user.image(:small)), @user %>
```

Comment: You make a good point @arun15thmay , but the code above returns an array and user.image won't work with the array. Maybe I can restrict devise to not allow two users with teh same username?

Comment: @TonyTambe If it is username, you can try restricting 2 users from having the same username. If it is the name of the user, I do not think restricting is a good idea. In any case, I believe my 2nd part of the code should be working if you use `<%= link_to (image_tag user.image(:small)), user %>` instead of `<%= user.image %>`

Comment: but that will list each user's image. I need to only list the user who I am getting with user_week, which returns ["username", number of reviews]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the user.image to display by using this in the view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
        <% if @user_week[0] == user.name %>
            <%= link_to (image_tag user.image(:small)), user %>
        <% end %>     
    <% end %>
```